# Undefined Index in registration form [PHP]

Tags: php, html, authentication, undefined-index

So I'm making a simple registration form, and for some reason, I keep getting undefined index for the following:

> Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\food\createacc.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\food\createacc.php on line 10
>
> Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\food\createacc.php on line 11

This is my code:

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
header("Location: dashboard.php");
}
require_once 'dbc.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);

$username = $DBcon->real_escape_string($username);
$password = $DBcon->real_escape_string($password);
$email = $DBcon->real_escape_string($email);

$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$check_username = $DBcon->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE         username='$username'");

$count=$check_username->num_rows;
if ($count==0) {
$query = "INSERT INTO users(username,password,email)     VALUES('$username','$hashed_password','$email')";
if ($DBcon->query($query)) {
$msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Plate Added.
       </div>";
    }else {
     $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Error.
       </div>";
    }
   } else {
    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
       <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Plate Already Taken.
      </div>";
   }
   $DBcon->close();
  }
  ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>fiveCAD - Login</title>
    <link href="/fonts" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="login-page">
      <div class="form">
        <form class="login-form">
        <form action="" method="post">
          <input type="text" name='username' placeholder="Username"/>
        </form>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <input type="password" name='password' placeholder="Password"/>
        </form>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <input type="text" name='email' placeholder="Email Address"/>
        </form>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <input type="submit" name="btn-signup" id="btn-signup" value="Create Account">
        </form>
        <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="login.php">Sign In</a></p>
        </form>
      </div>
      <center><i><font size="1">Copyright (C) 2017 - Please read <a href="tou.php">Terms of Use</a>.</i></center>
    </div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have multiple forms, you should only have one `<form>`. You also are open to SQL injections, and need to hash your users passwords.

Comment: @chris85 but why am I getting undefined index?

Comment: Because the `form` you submit has no `input`s in it. You are submitting this `<form action="" method="post">
          <input type="submit" name="btn-signup" id="btn-signup" value="Create Account">
        </form>` only.